# How to get data using angular $http.get() from action class in Struts2 project

Tags: angularjs

I am developing project using angular and struts2 + maven.
this is my action class

```
package com.ai.action;

import com.ai.model.PersonData;
import com.ai.model.Village;
import com.ai.service.PersonService;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public class AngularAction implements Action {

private Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonAction.class);

private List<Village> STSarray;
@Autowired
private PersonService  personService;

public String execute()
{
    List<Village> STSarray = personService.getAllVillage();

    logger.info("save method {}",getSTSarray());
    return SUCCESS;
}

public List<Village> getSTSarray() {
    return STSarray;
}

public void setSTSarray(List<Village> STSarray) {
    this.STSarray = STSarray;
}

}
```

Here i loaded data to 
    list
using DAO with hibernate. Data added successfully to array.
then i want to get this data to jsp page.

Struts.xml

```
    <action name="angularAction" class="com.ai.action.AngularAction">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="root">personData</param>
            <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
            <param name="noCache">true</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

this is my jsp page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>AJAX with Struts 2 using AngularJS</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    angular.module("demo", [])
            .controller("demoCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

                $scope.loadData = function () {

                    $http.get("angularAction").success(function (data) {

                        $scope.person = data;
                        console.log($scope.person);
                    });
                }
            });

</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="demoCtrl">
<table class="table table-striped">
<p><button data-ng-click="loadData()">
    Fetch data from server
</button></p>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Size</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in person">
    <td>{{item.country}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.size}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

But 
    console.log($scope.person); 
give me null.please help.

But when my action class is given below it working properly.

```
public class AngularAction implements Action{

//private PersonData personData = new PersonData();
private List<Village> Setstow =new ArrayList<Village>();
private Village village = new Village();
private Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AngularAction.class);
private PersonData personData = new PersonData();

public String execute() {

    personData.setFirstName("Mohaideen");
    personData.setLastName("Jamil");
    return SUCCESS;
}

public PersonData getPersonData() {
    return personData;
}

public void setPersonData(PersonData personData) {
    this.personData = personData;
}
```

As my idea please tell me How to get List STSarray data in Action class by using $http.get("angularAction").success(function (data).

Comment: is "angularAction" the correct URL? you can check it by using your browser's developer tools (usually you can access that through CTRL+SHIFT+I) then go to the "network" bar and see if the call is correct

Comment: also you set $scope.itemsdata = data; but then call console.log($scope.person); which is a different variable

Comment: where is the controller initialized? you are missing a line like this: app.controller('demoCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", MyController]); after the function declaration. and in the html code you call "loadData()" but the function in your controller is called "getDataFromServer"

Comment: regarding your edit. Have you tried renaming "STSarray" into "personData"? (also getSTSarray into getPersonData and setSTSarray into setPersonData )

Comment: also... change List<Village> STSarray = personService.getAllVillage(); into personData=personService.getAllVillage();

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your angular code:

1. Check if "angularAction" is the correct URL. That would point to something like http://yourserver/jsplocation/angularAction. for instance if your jsp is located at http://localhost/pages/page.jsp then the call will be http://localhost/pages/angularAction
   On top of that, is your angularAction returning the array in JSON? you can check that by typing the URL of your angularAction directly in your browser and see the result
2. inside the success function you set `$scope.itemsdata=data;` but then you call `console.log($scope.person);` which is a different variable never set inside the code
3. you never set the controller inside your module. Try this

   ```
   var MyController=function ($scope, $http) {
   $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
       $http.get("angularAction").success(
           function(data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.itemsdata = data;
               console.log($scope.itemsdata);
           }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){});
       };
   };

   app.controller('demoCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", MyController]);
   ```
4. In your HTML you call "loadData();" but the function you set in your controller is called "getDataFromServer"
5. You put a `<p>` tag (the one with the button) inside the `<table>` tag. You should move that out.

Server side there are other errors. You should call "personData" in your original code anything that's named STSarray, and also remove the type declaration in your "execute" method because that'd make it a local variable

```
package com.ai.action;

import com.ai.model.PersonData;
import com.ai.model.Village;
import com.ai.service.PersonService;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public class AngularAction implements Action {

private Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonAction.class);

private List<Village> personData;
@Autowired
private PersonService  personService;

public String execute()
{
    this.personData = personService.getAllVillage();

    logger.info("save method {}",getPersonData());
    return SUCCESS;
}

public List<Village> getPersonData() {
    return personData;
}

public void setPersonData(List<Village> personData) {
    this.personData = personData;
}

}
```

It would be a good idea to use your browser's developer tools (or better, firebug) in order to check your javascript code next time (even though i assume that if you use console.log() you know how to use your javascript console, but it should've warned you about the missing controller and everything else).

Comment: URL Is correct when i debug using My Intelijidea correctly go through the method in action class.

Comment: Sir thanks for your response.i am new to angula so can you give me real example match my requirement(angula +struts2 +hibernate)

Comment: Even if i wanted i don't know any tutorial about what you are asking for. Normally a question like this would be ignored on Stackoverflow but i had some free time and i have tried to help you but I think you are missing the basics here. Please open google and search for "angular struts2 hibernate tutorial" and try some of the links